# ASP.net Button on Postback gets a DNS error in IE

Tags: asp.net, dns, postback

I have a button on an ASP.net page.

```
<asp:Button Text="<%$Resources: WebResources, Export %>" ID="BtnExport" runat="server" OnClick="BtnExport_Click"/>
```

The issue is that when I try to export more than 130 items the page will not postback and go straight to the dns error page.  The code works fine in firefox, safari, and chrome.  The issue occurs in IE (only tested in 8).

I tried debugging.  I added a breakpoint at the start of the method and start of the PageLoad method and the error happened before it got to those points.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue seems to be I was passing too many characters in the Request URL.  IE only supports approximately 2048 characters in a URL.  Safari, Chrome and Firefox support at least 80,000.  Way to go IE.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the "Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages" in Internet Explorer.  Tools -> Options -> Advanced.

What is the error you see in IE with this disabled?

Comment: With Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages turned off it is the same error.